# MemorySection.get error trying to load item from custom YAMLConfiguration

Tags: java, yaml, bukkit

In a Bukkit plugin, I have a custom YAML file "locale.yml" where different languages and strings are stored. When the plugin is loaded without the locale file in place, it and the other files are created, but when a command gets a locale string, there is an internal error. Note that this is fixed upon a reload with the file still there.

The code for loading the file is as follows:

```
if (!localeFile.exists()) {
    this.saveResource("locale.yml", false);
    InputStream locStream = this.getResource("locale.yml");
    if(locStream != null){
        locale.setDefaults(locale);
    }
}
```

I understand that `locale.setDefaults(locale);` causes infinite recursion, but I cannot think of any other solutions. I have tried to remove that, removing the error but instead returning "null" (since there is no file to load from. this is **NOT** fixed by a server reload).

Stack trace (this is repeated):

`at org.bukkit.configuration.MemorySection.get(MemorySection.java:198) ...`

and

`at org.bukkit.configuration.MemorySection.getDefault(MemorySection.java:705) ...`

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this myself by replacing the load method with:

```
if (localeFile == null) {
    File localeFile = new File(this.getDataFolder(), "locale.yml");
}
locale = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(localeFile);

// Look for defaults in the jar
Reader localeStream = new InputStreamReader(this.getResource("locale.yml"));
if (localeStream != null) {
    YamlConfiguration loc = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(localeStream);
    locale.setDefaults(loc);
}
```